# Linear search throught vector[i] yealds 0ms response whilst vector.at(i) yealds time

Tags: c++, vector

I must add: I am calling my linear search 15 000 times and the lowest range i am looking within is up to 50 000 with each iteration. Thus meaning there are 15 000 * 50 000 look ups on the first iteration. This should take longer than 0ms.

I have this basic Linear search:

```
bool linearSearch(std::vector<int>&primes, int number, int range) {

    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        if (primes[i] == number)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I take time using:

```
void timeLinearSearch(std::vector<int>& primes) {
    clock_t start, stop;
    size_t NRND = 15000;    //  15000 primes per clock

    for (int N = 50000; N <= 500000; N += 50000)    // increase by 50k each iteration
    {
        for (int repeat = 0; repeat < 5; repeat++) {
            start = clock();
            for (int j = 0; j < NRND; j++) {
                linearSearch(primes, rand(), N);
            }
            stop = clock();
            std::cout << stop - start << ", " << N << std::endl;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem here is that the time taken is 0ms. The vector 'primes' has roughly 600 000 elements in it so the search stays within range.

In the linear search, if I change:

```
if(primes[i] == number)
```

to:

```
if(primes.at(i) == number)
```

then I get time > 0 taken for the search.

I have compared my linear search with the primes.at(i) to std::find() by:

```
for (int j = 0; j < NRND; j++) {
    std::find(primes.begin(), primes.begin() + N, rand());
}
```

and this is roughly 200ms faster than my .at() find.

Why is my search with std::vector[i] giving me 0ms time?

Comment: If you sort your vector you can use `std::lower_bound` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the compiler can see into the implementation of `linearSearch`, it can optimize it out entirely when you use `operator[]`, because there are no side effects. That is why you see zero time.

`at(..)`, on the other hand, has a side effect (throwing when the index is out of bounds) so the compiler has no option of optimizing it out.

You can fix your benchmark to ensure that the call is kept in place, for example, by counting the number of matches:

```
int count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < NRND; j++) {
    count += linearSearch(primes, rand(), N);
}
std::cout << stop - start << ", " << N << " " << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/43D9fm). Time goes down more than 100 times when you remove `count += ` from the code.

Comment: UV'd. My answer is poor in comprison with this.

Comment: @Bathsheba Don't sell your answer short: your observation that `at(..)` performs bounds checking while `operator[..]` does not is precisely the explanation of why OP's code behaves differently when he makes the change.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You were correct, I added bool result = linearSearch(primes, rand(), N); and I am now getting the same time as std::find(). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You do need to be careful with writing comparison code like this; do make sure you have a statistically rigourous way of interpreting your data. Assuming you do have this, here's an explanation:

`[i]` does not have to check if `i` is within the bounds of a vector, whereas `at(i)` **must** check.

That explains the difference in the speed: your compiler is able to generate faster code for `[]`.

Comment: Not sure if this is really the answer.  The OP states it takes no time to use `[]`, and `std::find` does take time and it does not use range checking either.

Comment: This i already know, that is why I added that i have checked with std::find() wich behaves like my linear search. The range is within range since the vector is beyond 600k elements and the highest i look for is 500k.

Comment: @NathanOliver: indeed I'm starting to think this is not the significant part of the story: the expert dasblinkenlight has, I think the correct answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree.  I think the code optimization is the most rational explanation.  Which is really funny as I was just talking in chat about how you have to force the compiler to stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me you are comparing apples and oranges.
You ask to find "rand()" element so it is a different number in every run

What about looking for elements like this (assuming you have N primes):
primes[N/10], primes[N/2], primes(3*N/4), ... for elements to be found
(add +1 if you want the item no to be found)

Careful, if your primes array is sorted in an increasing order, you might want to return false if primes[i] > number rather than going through the whole array (or even do dichotomy search) unless you are just looking at .at() evaluation

Comment: This isn't answering the question as to why the method takes no time at all to run.  Rather, this is providing some suggestions for optimization.

Comment: @Andrew not really, maybe he could have been lucky on the rand() for the [] and unlucky with the .at()