# Compiler optimising out parts of my code in release even though return value is taken care of and locked to if statement

Tags: c++

I asked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167161/linear-search-throught-vectori-yealds-0ms-response-whilst-vector-ati-yealds) question yesterday where my compiler apparently optimised out my linear search because i did not handle the return value.

I now have a binary search acting similarly even though the return value is clearly handled.

The code calling my binary search is as follow:

```
void timeBinarySearch(std::vector<int>& primes) {
    clock_t start, stop;
    size_t NRND = 10000;    //  10000 primes per seach
    for (int N = 50000; N <= 500000; N += 50000)    // alla mätpunkter
    {
        for (int repeat = 0; repeat < 5; repeat++) {
            start = clock();

            for (int j = 0; j < NRND; j++) {
                int ran = rand();
                int pos = binarySearch(primes, ran, N);    //  Handling the return value
                if (pos != -1 && primes[pos] != ran){   //  value of pos is requested here
                    std::cout << "Katastrof" << std::endl;
                }

            }
            stop = clock();

            double timeTaken = (1.0*(stop - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        }
    }
}
```

And the binarySearch function:

```
int binarySearch(std::vector<int>&primes, int number, int range) {
    int max = range;
    int min = 0;
    while (min <= max) {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if (primes[mid] == number)
            return mid;
        if (number < primes[mid])
            max = mid - 1;
        else
            min = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Above shows that the return value from binarySearch is saved into pos and even required for the following if statement. It works like a charm on debug mode but on release( I need to have the time taken i release mode ) it looks like the compiler optimises the binary search away. Any break point within the binarySearch function states

> The current breakpoint will not be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.

When stepping through the debugger in release mode it does not stop on the if statement requesting pos, probably optimising this one too.

Now i have similar problem as the question yesterday but this time the return value is taken care of.

I cant get any mesurable time running the binary search as it is considered 0ms run time for as lowest 10 000 * log(50 000) complexity, and at most 10 000 * log(500 000). This should take longer than 0 ms to execute.

Comment: Which compiler, which optimization flags, which operating system? How do you measure the time?

Comment: So you want to debug in release mode?

Comment: please post a [mcve] including input data

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch VS15 default, none specified, Windows 10

Comment: @LogicStuff Debugging in release is not the problem. I just included that I had putted breakpoints within the binary search that is never hit

Comment: BTW, you should run several dozens of million iterations at least (more precisely, have a total execution time exceeding half a second). Computers are able to do a typical *elementary* machine instruction in nanoseconds. Read the *answers* section of http://norvig.com/21-days.html ; and Windows `clock` function is computing *real elapsed* time (not CPU time, as it should) with some coarse resolution. With a Linux system installed on a recent PC, you'll probably have "better" time measurement, see [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 2):

At a very rough approximation, your search is only ~500,000 instructions. If a processor is running 1 instruction per cycle, at 1GHz, (completely inaccurate for modern processors, but close enough to get an idea of how fast computers are), it will run 500,000 instructions in 0.5ms. You're computer is probably running the loop even faster than this.

Comment: *The current breakpoint will not be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.
*  
Is key in this question.